Version mismatch after "flutter pub upgrade --major-versions"
The flutter pub upgrade --major-versions seems to be updating to incompatible versions; for example, its response includes:

Changed 3 constraints in pubspec.yaml:
package_info_plus: ^5.0.0 -> ^8.0.0
share_plus: ^7.0.0 -> ^9.0.0
ffigen: ^11.0.0 -> ^12.0.0

Then a flutter run fails with:

Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 3.2.3.
Because ffigen 12.0.0 requires SDK version >=3.3.0 <4.0.0 and no
versions of ffigen match >12.0.0 <13.0.0, ffigen ^12.0.0 is forbidden.
So, because [project name] depends on ffigen ^12.0.0, version solving failed.

How can I make the flutter pub upgrade --major-versions command only upgrade to compatible plugin versions?

specify the SDK constrains in your pubspec.yaml. Add an constrain for dart SDK version in your pubspec.yaml. It will help the package manger consider your SDK version.
environment:
sdk: ">=3.2.3 <4.0.0"

and instead of using --major-versions you can update the package manually
`flutter pub upgrade package_name`


Thanks, but that would still give me 3.2.3, and I want to be able to update with --major-versions.
